# "Read-only global varName should not be modified" problem in an Cloud9 environment

Tags: javascript, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

I'm a begginer using a Cloud9 environment that runs in js.

I have an assignement in which I need to use a global variable that will be modified every time a function is called. To my knowledge I have to use a global since I need to store the current value of the variable to be able to change it everytime the function is called.

At first I got a warning message saying:
`VarName is not defined, please fix or add /*global VarName*/`
Which I fixed by adding what is said there.

Now I get this warning:
`Read-only global VarName should not be modified.`

I've been stuck with this for a long time and could really use an advice on how to solve this.

These are the lines of the code involved in what I say:

```
/*global distance*/

let distance=0;

// Function that returns the total distance traveled
function distanceTraveled(speed){
    distance=distance+speed*(1/6);
    return distance;
}

function distanceToTarget(totalDistance){
    totalDistance=totalDistance-distanceTraveled(0);
    return totalDistance;
}
```

Note: I've been only using js for some days and have little coding experience.

Comment: welcome. please share your code.

Comment: Done. @DanielA.White

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you might not need `/*global distance*/` at the top, if `distance` is defined in the same file.

Otherwise, you can try putting the bellow comment above the line you are modifying `distance`:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-native-reassign
```